# Searching Two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a Java newbie and need help with Arrays.

I have two arrays right now.

```
int [] array1 = {2,5,7};
int [] array2 = {3,5,9};
```

I have to find the first matching elements between the two arrays which is clearly 5. Obviously first we are going to look through the elements in array1 and then look up these elements to see if they are in array2 as well. I'm pretty sure I have to use a loop, just not sure which and how to code it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your tried code ?

Comment: give it a try with a for-each loop ;) write some code and if you got a specific question come back here!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to search for an element in an array of type int.

Comment: Thanks Parker...I'm gonna try a for-each loop right now. I'll post back in a few minutes...just needed to know which loop to use as a starting point :)

Comment: Ok, so I almost have the code correct. I have the two arrays I posted above. I just don't understand how I go about finding the first matching element. I know that the element is 8. I'm using a for each loop. But how do I compare the two arrays to search for that matching int value? I know how to compare the arrays to see if they match exactly, but not just the first element.

Comment: Use two (for-)loops und compare the contents of the arrays in the inner loop. Break out of the loop when you find your first value.

Comment: Optimised way of doing this is using HashMap. But I believe you would want to learn Loop first. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you

```
for(int index1=0;index1<array1.length();index1++)
 {
 for(int index2=0;index2<array2.length();index2++)
  {
   if(array1[index1]==array2[index2])
   {
    System.out.println(array1[index1]+" is present in both array.");
   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something alike the following

If you are merely looking for common elements in the arrays, at any index:

```
    //Loop through array1
    for (int inArray1 : array1) {
        //For each element in array1, loop through array2
        for (int inArray2 : array2) {
            //If they are equal, we have found a common element
            if (inArray1 == inArray2) {
                System.out.println("First common element: " + inArray1);
                break; //We've found it, no need to keep going
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want the matching elements to be at a common index:

```
    //In-case the arrays have a different length
    int commonLength = Math.min(array1.length, array2.length);
    //For each element in BOTH of the arrays
    for(int index = 0; index < commonLength; index++) {
        //If the corresponding elements are equal, we have found our common
        if(array1[index] == array2[index]) {
            System.out.println("First matching element: " + array1[index] + " at index " + index);
            break; //We've found it, no need to keep going
        }
    }
```

Comment: I actually found a similar question to mine and got basically the exact same answer as your code, just had different variables. Really appreciate the help!